# Visual Studio 2010 unable to disable CSS Validation (after removing validation options)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, visual-studio-2010

Hoping I can get some idea on troubleshooting this problem.

At the end of the build sequence on this solution I am working on, I get a list of Errors that have occurred due to CSS validation failed. There are only "CSS" errors that appear. I am trying to suppress these "errors"

**Actions I have done so far to troubleshoot:**

- I have removed the check boxes under 
  Tools > Options > Text Editor > CSS > Miscellaneous > Errors 
  Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Validation > Options

  Closed/Re-opened Visual Studio but this particular Solution/Project does not pick up the change and continues to display the CSS issues as "errors" when built.

  Other solutions I create behave as I need to, however, i.e. CSS validation is suppressed
- Tried resetting my environment (Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings)
- Also running "devenv /resetuserdata" (which I believe is the same as above)

How can I go about troubleshooting this issue on this solution to suppress the CSS "errors" or at least make them appear under "warnings"?

---

Running: Visual Studio 2010 Pro SP1 on Win 7 x64
This affects a ASP.NET MVC 2 web application

(ps. most of these CSS issues are from a third-party library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to be a post build minifier fault with MicrosoftAjax. If I commented the .csproj file's post build section pertaining to MicrosoftAjax, it worked without issue!

I take this to be a bug with the Microsoft Ajax Minifier (version 4.62.4618.15618).